# Selecting Squarespace Elements with CSS for Display Size

Tags: css, squarespace

The end goal here is to vertically stack a row of three horizontal elements based on the screen size of the user. The html of that row is below:

```
 <div class="row sqs-row" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1574264134211_429">
```

Right now the objects eventually respond to the screen size and stack vertically, but this happens far too late and after the objects start to overlap. I believe the css below is correct for adjusting the elements outside of the actual element selection itself - that is where I am struggling:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
     .col.sqs-col-4.span-4 {width: 100%;}
}
```

I know that `yui` elements change on load screen, so I probably want to target either the `block-yui`'s or somehow the child classes of the row's class. Below is the html for the first of the three elements in the row:

```
<div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4">
    <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" 
     id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1574100037089_27115">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
```

I have tried a ton of different ways to select these elements, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are the styles you're applying merely being overridden by higher specificity selectors? Also, you have a typo in your media query… not sure if that is an issue with the transposition to the question or is actually the root of your problem.

Comment: Note that the markdown in Squarespace can change (in some cases subtly, in other cases dramatically) based on whether you are logged-in and viewing the site via edit-mode (/config) vs. not logged-in and viewing the site as a user. Keep that in mind when targeting elements within the Squarespace grid system and testing CSS. This and other factors are why Including a link to the page in question (and the view-only password if necessary, as in for trial-mode sites) may increase the amount and quality of responses when it comes to Squarespace-related questions.